# Script Transformation Editor used for ingesting Data from csv not recognizing new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have an `SSIS` data flow task that needs to load a CSV file into a table. The table already exists in production, I am just trying to add new columns to it.

Now the first component in the data flow task is to load the CSV file using a `Script Transformation` editor, I am using this package as it is legacy and currently in production so I can't use another component instead of it.

I had created the column in the Inputs and Outputs section and also made sure the component exists in the `Database`. Then run the data flow task but it seems like the component is just not able to load the new column. It's all NULL. I double-checked to see if the file has the values and the file does have the columns.

Except when I run the Data Flow task I am for whatever reason not able to see the new column in the `Data Viewer`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you haven't refreshed the source, and then added it to **all** the relevant data flow pipes, then the separate nodes won't see the new column.

Comment: I figured it out. The column I had was like FOO_BAR when the script was expecting FOOBAR and was rejecting any column with _ , thanks for your help